# Get invalid view size when I override super's viewDidLayoutSubviews from sub class of UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing iOS UI with auto layout.

Because I need to set corner radius of view's layer for make view looks like circle, get actual view's size is necessary. (I couldn't change layer by constraints)

Finally, I realize I can get view's real size in viewDidLayoutSubviews and I looks well. But when I called it's super method, size becomes wrong value.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    // [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    if (_viewProfileCoverForReward) {
        float circleSize = imageViewOppositeProfile.frame.size.width;
        _viewProfileCoverForReward.layer.cornerRadius = circleSize / 2;

        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%ld)circle size : %f", super.missionData.missionID, circleSize]);
    }
}
```

Here is my code and it works well. But in my opinion, don't call super's method is not good and why I must not call super's method if I want to get view's real size. It doesn't make sense!

Comment: What do you mean by "invalid", is it "nil" or is it wrong?

Comment: In addition, unlike `viewWill/DidAppear` and `viewWill/DidDisAppear`, you do not have to call super when you override `viewDidLayourSubviews`.

Comment: @EricQian Sorry, I edited question right now. For example, if I call super's method, I got 120. But If I don't call super's method, I got 80.